# Best way to create a reusable modal window in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using html5, angularjs, bootstrap. So each one of them gives many options to create a modal window. Whole of my website has 2 things, one is confirmation dialog or form dialog. So which is the best reusable approach. Should i use html5 or create a directive ?

Comment: What about `angular ui-bootstrap`? https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: Use what best suits your needs. Lean toward angular module/directive resources before looking at bootstrap.js. There are numerous modules you can use that are readily available

Comment: you should use https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal. If you want to create confirm modal box then you should create a factory and override  modals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments [ui-bootstrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) is very useful.
Just for an example here is a factory for confirm modal that you can extend according to your use case:

```
yourApp.factory("dialog", ["$modal",
  function($modal) {
    var dialogService = {
      confirm: function(options) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'partials/confirm-modal.html',
          controller: ['$scope',
            function($scope) {
              $scope.header = options.header;
              $scope.body = options.body;
              $scope.confirmText = options.confirmText || "Close";
              $scope.cancelText = options.cancelText || "Confirm";
              $scope.hideCancelButton = options.hideCancelButton;
              $scope.cancel = function() {
                modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
              };
              $scope.confirm = function() {
                modalInstance.close();
              };
            }
          ]
        });
        return modalInstance.result;
      }
    }
  }
])
```

And here is your template:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn close" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
    <h4 id="noteLabel" class="modal-title">{{header}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<p ng-bind-html="body" style="font-size: 16px"></p>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button ng-show="!hideCancelButton" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">{{cancelText}}</button>
    <button ng-click="confirm()" class="btn btn-primary">{{confirmText}}</button>
</div>
```